# Split ansible role's tasks into multiple files

Tags: ansible

This is my ansible role:

```
/roles
  /foo
    /tasks
      main.yml             <----- I want to split this
```

The `main.yml` file is really big, so I want to split it into multiple files, and call them in sequence.

```
/roles
  /foo
    /tasks
      run-this-first.yml            <--- 1st
      run-this-last.yml             <--- last
      run-this-second.yml           <--- 2nd
```

How do I invoke those files, and how do I ensure they are run in order?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it with [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html):

```
/roles
  /foo
    /tasks
      main.yml
      run-this-first.yml            <--- 1st
      run-this-last.yml             <--- last
      run-this-second.yml           <--- 2nd
```

As you can notice that there is also `main.yml` inside the `tasks` directory and your `main.yml` simply contains this:

```
---
- include_tasks: run-this-first.yml
- include_tasks: run-this-second.yml
- include_tasks: run-this-last.yml
```

Answer (score 9):

You essentially have 2 ways (two builtin modules to be precise) to achieve this. Displayed for both approaches is how your `tasks/main.yml` file might look like:

- **[`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html) module**

  ```yaml
  ---
  - name: First tasks
    ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
      file: run-this-first.yml
  - name: second tasks
    ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
      file: run-this-second.yml
  - name: Last tasks
    ansible.builtin.include_tasks:
      file: run-this-last.yml
  ```
- **[`import_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html) module**

  ```yaml
  ---
  - name: First tasks
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks:
      file: run-this-first.yml
  - name: second tasks
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks:
      file: run-this-second.yml
  - name: Last tasks
    ansible.builtin.import_tasks:
      file: run-this-last.yml
  ```

Note that, according to the [ansible documentaion about Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) the **`import_tasks`** module is the suggested way to go.

The difference in the above examples is really just `include_tasks/import_tasks`.
However, which module you use will affect *how* the tasks are imported as the `include_tasks` imports tasks in a dynamic manner, while `import_tasks` imports them in a static way.

A comparison of the two approaches can be found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#comparing-includes-and-imports-dynamic-and-static-re-use) in the official [guide about re-using artifacts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html) and you can read more about when you might want to use which module [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-files-and-roles) in this same guide.